# DRF ORM: Aggregate, annotate and remove duplicates all in the same query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, aggregate, django-orm

Knowing that I have the following models:

```py
class Merchant(BaseModel):
    business_name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='merchant'
        # ...
    )
    # other fields...


class Sale(BaseModel):
    merchant = ForeignKey(
        Merchant,
        related_name='sale_merchant'
        # ...
    )
    statue = CustomCharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=[(DRAFT, DRAFT)), (COMPLETED, COMPLETED), (FAILD, FAILD)],
        # ...
    )
    # other fields like total, discount, data...


class SaleItem(BaseModel):
    quantity = PositiveIntegerField()
    product = ForeignKey(
        Product,
        # ...
    )
    sale = ForeignKey(
        Sale,
        related_name='sold_item'
        # ...
    )
    # other fields...
```

As well as a `Product` model, and a `User` model (alongside other information, the `User` model stores the user's city as a reference to the `City` model).

As you can see, a `Sale`, may have multiple `SaleItem`s, a `SaleItem` refers to a single `Product` and the `Sale` itself, and has a quantity.

Finally, a `Sale` represents a set of products that were **sold by us to a specific merchant** .

I want to get the number of items of each product that were sold to each merchant. An example of the output I'm trying to achieve (`id` replesents the `id` of the first `SaleItem` that links product `X` to merchant `Y`):

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id  |  Merchant Name | Denomination |  Quantity  |  Merchant City  |
|-----|----------------|--------------|------------|-----------------|
|  1  |   Merchant_1   |  Product_1   |    133     |     London      |
|-----|----------------|--------------|------------|-----------------|
|  2  |   Merchant_1   |  Product_2   |    1234    |      NYC        |
|-----|----------------|--------------|------------|-----------------|
|  3  |   Merchant_2   |  Product_1   |     54     |     Tokyo       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Denomination represents the products name.

I tried many ways but could not achieve the exact same thing. I can do it with multiple steps, but I need to do it in a single query, no matter how complex it gets.

Finally, I need that `id` to fetch the info of the individual items of each product sold to a merchant, so if there's a better way to achieve that, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should yield the desired result

```py
qs = Merchant.objects.all()
# Join through Sale and SaleItem by the use of related_name
qs = qs.annotate(product_id=F("sale_merchant__sold_item__product__id"))
# Gather relevant data
qs = qs.annotate(denomination=F("sale_merchant__sold_item__product__denomination"))
qs = qs.annotate(individual_quantity=F("sale_merchant__sold_item__quantity"))
qs = qs.annotate(city_name=F("user__city__name"))
# Keeping only relevant data and discarding the model layer to allow for grouping
qs = qs.values("id", "product_id", "name", "denomination", "city_name")
# Froce a grouping while summing the quantities
qs = qs.annotate(quantity=Sum("individual_quantity"))
# Keeping only the desired data
qs = qs.values("name", "denomination", "quantity", "city_name")
```

You'll notice that the result will be a dict with `"name", "denomination", "quantity", "city_name"` as keys.

As a side note, your `related_name`s should be plurialized as there is more than one Sale per Merchant and more than one SaleItem per Sale. `sales` and `sold_items` are fitting I think.